# Is it possible to iterate over elements in a list and return chunks of the list based on repeating characters?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have data stored in a list that follows a pattern. The data comes from reading a file line by line and appending certain lines to a list. When I print the list, the data follows an order, which is great.

Can I read through that list to pick out chunks of data?

For example, if I have in the list:

`['|CODE|', 'name', 'group', 'info', '|CODE_1|', 'name', 'group', 'info',]` and so on...

Is is possible to return the strings between the |CODE| parts?

Also, the strings between each |CODE| string may not be the same length, ie there may be 4 strings between them or 6 or 10 or 1 etc.

Let me know if I can amend my question in any way :)

I haven't got any code yet as I was unsure on how to tackle the problem.

Comment: are values like `|CODE_1|` go literally  in your list?

Comment: Since the question is "is this possible?", then the answer is "yes".

Comment: Since the question is "is this possible?", then the answer is "yes".

Comment: I can append the starting element in a way such that it contains the | ... | yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow a few steps:

1. Create the final list you need,
2. Iterate over the list after the first element is `'|CODE|'`,
3. Add element to the current chunk of data,
4. If you detect a new chunk, store the current chunk and create a new one.

```py
lst = ["|CODE|", "name", "group", "info", "|CODE_1|", "name", "group", "info"]

chunk = []
chunks = []
for e in lst[lst.index("|CODE|") + 1 :]:
    if e.startswith("|CODE"):
        chunks.append(chunk)
        chunk = []
    else:
        chunk.append(e)
if chunk:
    chunks.append(chunk)
print(chunks)
# [['name', 'group', 'info'], ['name', 'group', 'info']]
```

If you need to include the string that start a chunk:

```py
chunk = ["|CODE|"]  # start chunk with first marker
...
        chunk = [e]  # each chunk start with the marker
# [['|CODE|', 'name', 'group', 'info'], ['|CODE_1|', 'name', 'group', 'info']]
```

Result:

```py
lst = ["|CODE|", "name", "group", "info", "|CODE_1|", "name", "group", "info", "|CODE_2|", "name", "group", "info", "|CODE_3|", "name", "group", "info"]

chunks = []
chunk = ["|CODE|"]
for e in lst[lst.index("|CODE|") + 1 :]:
    if e.startswith("|CODE"):
        chunks.append(chunk)
        chunk = [e]
    else:
        chunk.append(e)
if chunk:
    chunks.append(chunk)
print(chunks)
# [['|CODE|', 'name', 'group', 'info'], ['|CODE_1|', 'name', 'group', 'info'], ['|CODE_2|', 'name', 'group', 'info'], ['|CODE_3|', 'name', 'group', 'info']]
```

#### How to start this kind of algorithms.

You need to proceed step by step.

1. You know that you need to iterate over the list, so do the for loop,
2. You need a list of `chunks`, easy to do, create an empty list before the loop. It's your final data structure you want to fill,
3. You want short `chunk` of data to be stored inside `chunks`:

   1. Initialize it empty before the loop,
   2. Add the code to append a `chunk` inside `chunks`.
   3. When does a `chunk` should be added? When detecting the "new chunk marker", a `"|CODE"` starting string. Do the if.
   4. And reset the `chunk` to an empty list, now, you start a new `chunk`,
4. What if don't detect a new `chunk`? Add the value to current `chunk`,

Each step is simple in itself, but the whole process can seems overwhelming. When you don't know where to start, split into small task, divide the complexity. And don't hesitate to sub divide if a step seems too complex to be done easily. When you progress in the writing of the algorithm, try to validate your steps by running your code and check that the result of your current work match your expectation.

Comment: hi again! this code did seem to work but is only returning the last code marker in the last and the strings that follow. there's multiple code markers beforehand.

Comment: @Jack What's missing? Can you give an example?

Comment: "|CODE|", "name", "group", "info", "|CODE_1|", "name", "group", "info", "|CODE_2|", "name", "group", "info", "|CODE_3|", "name", "group", "info"                            so for the example here, the code would only return from CODE_3 onwards and not the other 'chunks'

Comment: I updated my answer to show you the return value with your input, please show me what's wrong.

Comment: I dont know what to tell you other than its only returning the last chunk and not others. it could be something else in my code further up interfering so will have to troubleshoot

Comment: [edit] your question to add your code and your output. If it doesn't works for you, you probably changed something somewhere.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue, it was other code interfering! thanks for the help

Comment: So the code in the answer is working for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

`yourlist[yourlist.index('|CODE|')+1:yourlist.index('|CODE_1|')]`

`list.index` gets the index of the strings that you desire. The rest is just a slice to slice that list between the desired indices